# I cant extrude in Z Axis

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

Iam attempting to extrude in Z Axis iam pressing <kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but I can't extrude the plane.

I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/OHg-CHcflPM?t=1299.

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Are you pressing the keys one after another or all at the same time? What exactly are you seeing on the screen?

Comment: I edited it now you can see what I see.

Comment: and one after other

Answer (score 2):

### Don't press G

The E shortcut is for the "Extrude Region and Move".

[image]

The move (or grab) command you are trying to recall with G is alredy active. So by pressing G, you are activating the Vertex Slide option of the grab command.

Just press E and then Z to restrict the movement because you are already grabbing the object around.

Or yuo can press E and then Esc to Extrude the region only. After that you can activate the grabbing with G and restrict the movement with Z.